# how to use a refined number in erlang?

Tags: erlang

How i can use my refined number as shown below :

```
1> game:num().
provide a number between 1 and 100 : 10.              
10 is not my number. It is greater than 10.
provide a number between 11 and 100 : 44.
44 is not my number. It is lesser than 44.
provide a number between 1 and 43 :
```

Once you've refined the lower/upper bound, you have to use that. So the last message should be:

"provide a number between `11` and `43`".

Comment: Where's the source for `generate:num`?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

You just need to keep track of two bounds (upper and lower) to achieve what you want. I'm not providing code, though.